# How to compute a mean of a specific column of a matrix, excluding a given value IN MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, logical-operators, mean

I have a 1000x7 matrix whose columns present some values equal to `-99`.

I want to compute the mean of each column separately because I'm building a table using `fprintf`, *but* I want the mean to be computed excluding the `-99` values.

For instance, taking matrix `A`, I've tried

```
mean(A(A(:,1) ~= -99))
```

and it works for the computation of the first column mean.

However, when I try

```
mean(A(A(:,2) ~= -99))
```

for the second column, the result is **exactly equal** to the result of the first column.

What's wrong in that?
Thanks a lot in advance for your tips!

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the index values to first column only.

Try

`mean(A(A(:,2) ~= -99),2)` %for 2nd column

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't work. This computes a column vector containing the mean value of each row, excluding the -99 cases.

Answer (score 1):

In short: You need to specify the column when reading the values:

```
mean(A(A(:,2) ~= -99, 2))
```

A longer version: `A(:,1) ~= -99`returns an `1000 x 1` logical array, so does `A(:,2) ~= -99`. When indexing with logical arrays Matlab effectively flattens both arrays, and extracts the values for which the logical array is `true`.

If the logical array `B`has `M` elements and the array that is being indexed into, `A`, has `N` elements where `M <= N` Matlab will only operate on the first `M` elements of `B`i.e. `C = A(B)` would be equivalent to*

```
C = A(1:M);
C = C(B);
```

In your example you are indexing into a `1000 x 7` array with a `1000 x 1` logical array, which makes all calls only consider the first 1000 elements, i.e. the first column. You therefore need to specify which column(s) you want the logical index to apply to.

*If `B` is an `1xM` array the resulting array will also be reshaped into an `1xM` array, for all other cases an `Mx1` array is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your short explanation falls in the same case as what searcoding said, didn't work. The "2" as the second argument of "mean" makes this function compute row means.

Comment: @WagnerMoreira I accidentally put the `2` at the wrong side of the paranthesis, should be correct now.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is, for say, the first column:

```
mean(A(find(A(:,1) ~= -99),1))
```

For example:

```
>> A

A =

     1     2
     1     3
   -99     4
     1     5
```

Then,

```
>> find(A(:,1)~=-99)

ans =

     1
     2
     4
```

And,

```
>> mean(A(find(A(:,1)~=-99),1))

ans =

     1
```

Comment: @WagnerMoreira: Great! :) Do accept the answer (or possibly another, better one) if it was what you were looking for. This helps to mark the question as solved and thus may benefit the community.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a vector, `A(:,1)~=-99`, to index into an array so it's only accessing values in the first column.  Here's an example of how you can do this calculation for each column in your array:

```
A = [1 2 3; -99, 4, 3; 10 4 8];

for col = 1:3
    index = A(:,col) ~= -99;
    mean(A(index,col))
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I cannot use for in this case, because it's a value that should be computed inside a fprintf calling.

Comment: Why does it need to be computed inside fprint?  Assign a variable to to mean value and pass that to fprint.